# Can I restrict the root to a single browser?

Tags: security

I want to be able restrict myself to firefox. I do not want to be able to use any other browser. So if I install chrome or any other browser, I don't want them to work on my Linux machine.

Here is the problem, I have root access. Is this possible without giving up my root access?

To be more specific, I know that the root user cannot really be prevented from installing and using a software, but I want it to be at least difficult for me, so that if I want to circumvent it, it should only be through a live-CD.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

There is nothing root can do to prevent root from undoing it later. There's not even a way for root to make it difficult to undo something later.

One way to make it slightly harder would be to blacklist webkitgtk3 in your package manager. Or remove your package manager altogether, and mount /usr as read-only. But you couldn't keep a later version of you from un-blacklisting webkitgtk3, or re-installing a package manager and mounting /usr read-write. And none of those are really that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be browsing as root.  root can override any permission blocks you put in place, so restrictions don't work.

You can remove execute permissions from any other browsers' executables.  This will prevent other users from running them.  It is possible to enable group execute permissions to allow certain users to use alternate browsers.

If your OS has a firewall it may be possible to restrict which programs can connect outbound on the web ports by program.  This would be effect for root unless you remove the restriction.  Most package managers connect to their repositories using web protocols, so you may need to add rules to allow them to connect outbound.